# Can't create an HttpRequestClient

Tags: android, android-studio, http, kotlin, httpclient

When I try to create a new HttpRequestClient using `HttpClients.createDefault()`, I get this error:

`java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; in class Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; or its superclasses (declaration of 'org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes2.dex)`

This is what my code looks like:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpException
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils
import java.io.IOException

internal class HttpRequestClient {
    private lateinit var httpClient: CloseableHttpClient

    @Throws(IOException::class, HttpException::class)
    fun makeGETRequest(uri: String?): String {
        val request = HttpGet(uri)
        return processRequest(request)
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class, HttpException::class)
    fun makePOSTRequest(uri: String?, jsonBody: String?): String {
        val post = HttpPost(uri)
        post.addHeader("content-type", "application/json")
        post.entity = StringEntity(jsonBody)
        return processRequest(post)
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class, HttpException::class)
    private fun processRequest(request: HttpUriRequest): String {
        var result = ""
        HttpClients.createDefault().use { httpClient ->
            httpClient.execute(request).use { response ->
                if (response.statusLine.statusCode != 200) {
                    throw HttpException(
                        "Request was unsuccessful " + response.statusLine.statusCode
                    )
                }
                result = EntityUtils.toString(response.entity)
            }
        }
        return result
    }

    companion object {
        private var httpRequestClient: HttpRequestClient? = null
        val instance: HttpRequestClient?
            get() {
                if (httpRequestClient == null) {
                    httpRequestClient = HttpRequestClient()
                }
                return httpRequestClient
            }
    }

    init {
        httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault()
    }
}
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: What is `HttpRequestClient` class?

Comment: @Sergey Originally, I included the block of code that was causing the problem, but that block of code is part of the `HttpRequestClient` class. I've updated my post and included the entire code for that class.